# Traversing JSON in Haskell with wreq - key issues

Tags: json, haskell, traversal, wreq

I'm trying to traverse some JSON response I'm getting from the OpenWeatherMap API but I'm getting some issues to retrieve some values. Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens (_String, key)
import Network.Wreq

myAPIKey :: String
myAPIKey = "my_api_key_here"

conditionsQuery :: String -> String -> String -> String
conditionsQuery city country key = 
   "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" ++ city ++ "," ++ country ++ "&appid=" ++ key

main = do
    print "What's the city?"
    city <- getLine
    print "And the country?"
    country <- getLine

    r <- get (conditionsQuery city country myAPIKey)

    print $ r ^. responseBody . key "name" . _String
    print $ r ^. responseBody . key "cod" . _String
    print $ r ^. responseBody . key "id" . _String
```

The issue is that only the value of "cod" is returned ("200" in that case).  The values for "name" and "id" appear as `""`, if we try with London,GB, Chicago, US (for instance). Yet the response body looks like:

```
{
   ...
   "id": 2643743,
   "name": "London",
   "cod": 200
}
```

I first thought it was a type mismatch, but 200 is an `Int` there (unless I'm mistaken?) so I am not sure where the issue lies? `""` seems to indicate that those 2 keys (`id` and `name`) do not exist, but they do.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response body does not look like that.

According to https://openweathermap.org/forecast5, the key `"cod"` appears at the outermost level of the JSON object, but `"id"` and `"name"` do not.

```
{
    "city":{
        "id":1851632,
        "name":"Shuzenji",
        ...
        }
    "cod":"200",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well spotted thanks! However, if we look at this: https://openweathermap.org/current, both "name" and "id" appear at the outermost level...

Comment: @DavidB. When querying by city ID, "name" and "id" appear at the outermost; when querying by city name, they are not there... I won't design APIs like that :(